# Moving bytes from different data types in RPGLE

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Say I have this program interface and those variables:

```
dcl-pi *n varchar(5000);       
  fileName char(10) const;     
  newRecord char(5000) const;  
end-pi;     

dcl-s valueNew char(5000) inz; 
dcl-s ptrMyGraph pointer inz(*null);
dcl-s myGraphic graph(160) based(ptrMyGraph);
```

Now I move a piece of the big entry string, that is a record format, in the `valueNew` variable.
It is a `graphic(40)` subfield.

```
valueNew = %subst(newRecord:i:fieldHeader.length);
```

Then I copy the memory space of `valueNew` to the real graphic variable.

```
ptrMyGraph = %alloc(fieldHeader.length);
memcpy(ptrMyGraph:%addr(valueNew):fieldHeader.length);
```

I should obtain a representable graphic variable in theory. But that's not the case.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I am concerned with the length you are moving. `memcpy` expects bytes, but is your length in characters? The two are not the same for graphic. There is a lot missing here that is causing me to speculate.

Comment: The field length returned by the API call is set to 80 for the graph(40), so I suppose it is right

Comment: Have you looked at the fields in debug to determine if there is any automatic conversion going on behind the scenes? I don't think `memcpy` will do any conversion, but putting a graphic field in a char field may.

Comment: Where's the data coming from?  Have you looked at the hex representation in debug?  Is it correct or corrupted?  Possibly by an ASCII-->EBCDIC conversion?   What's actually in the data?  If Unicode, UCS2 is probably a better choice...

Comment: I debugged and saw no differences in the hex representation between valueNew and the original data structure field. I will post the images.

Comment: I say you haven't included all the code.

Comment: `I should obtain a representable graphic variable in theory.` How do you know that you don't? What are you getting instead? That is, what is the **problem**? (Ideally, edit the question for adding detail.)